# How to convert Julian date to normal date (YYYY-MM-DD) in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to convert Julian Date values into normal date format (YYYY-MM-DD) in snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, you can convert a Julian Date to a normal date (YYYY-MM-DD) using the `TO_DATE()` function. Here's how you can do it:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(JULIAN_DATE_COLUMN) AS NORMAL_DATE
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Replace `JULIAN_DATE_COLUMN` with the name of the column containing Julian dates in your table, and `YOUR_TABLE` with the name of your table.

For example, if your table is named `dates_table` and the column containing Julian dates is `julian_date`, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(julian_date) AS normal_date
FROM dates_table;
```

This query will return the Julian dates converted to normal dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Thanks for your Input @Laura shoebel. but the given suggestion is not working as expected. 
example : 
SELECT TO_DATE('2459697') AS NRML_DT; --- 1970-01-29 output. 
It producing wrong/invalid data result

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I forgot that the `TO_DATE` function doesn't directly support Julian dates in the sense of the count of days. You could try to recalculate corresponding date using appropriate algorithms or libraries.
```
WITH julian_date_table AS (
  SELECT 2459697 AS julian_date -- Example Julian date
)
SELECT 
  julian_date,
  DATEADD(DAY, julian_date - 2440588, '1582-10-15') AS normal_date
FROM julian_date_table;
```

Comment: Thank you again.
Sorry if I misleading. Here is my input and expected output :
INPUT           :   2459697
Expected Output :   2022-04-27
the given code is producing the output in YYYY-MM-DD format but not the expected value. May I know what is the significance of given middle and last parameter value in DATEADD() function.  Do I need to change it . Kindly advice.

Comment: I believe Laura meant to say: select dateadd(DAY, 2459697 - 2440588, '1970-01-01'); Explanation: 2440588 is the Julian date for 1970-01-01. So we are adding the difference in days between 2459697 and 1970-01-01 to get the date 2022-04-27.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function which converts julian date. (Change below timezone to your timezone)

```
create or replace function JulianToGregorianDate(JulianDate numeric(18, 0))
  returns TIMESTAMP_TZ
  as--logic to convert JDE Julian date to normal date format
  $$
    CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles',dateadd(day,(IFF(JulianDate=0, NULL, JulianDate) % 1000) -1,dateadd(year,(IFF(JulianDate=0, NULL, JulianDate) / 1000),'1900-01-01')))
  $$
  ;
```

You can then use this function to convert the dates in tables.
Ex: `select JulianToGregorianDate(Column_julian) from table`